# Why my git repo in my work directory can know the change of .vimrc?

Tags: git, vim

My work folder is:

```
/Users/username/work/myapp
```

I manage my source under myapp by git.

But when I changed ~/.vimrc file.I run `git status` under myapp path.It shows me:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .vimrc
```

Why?

Comment: what do you get when you do `ls -l .vimrc` in the project directory? Maybe a symbolic link?

Comment: Thank you.I have do that,it shows `-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff  8  7 12 13:03 .vimrc`

Comment: how about `ls -l ~/.vimrc`?

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  staff  38  7 10 10:22 /Users/username/.vimrc -> /Users/username/work/myapp/.vimrc`

Comment: I should do:`unlink /Users/username/.vimrc`.Thank you:)

Comment: Why did you a) put a .vimrc in your project directory and b) link your ~/.vimrc to it?

Comment: That's did by other person:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `.vimrc` in your home directory is a symbolic link to the `.vimrc` in your project directory. That means they are the same file and the original one is in the project directory. To stop this behavior, you can remove the link, and copy the file to your home directory:

```
rm /Users/username/.vimrc
cp /Users/username/work/myapp/.vimrc /Users/username/
```

Comment: Yes.I did: `unlink /Users/username/.vimrc`.Thank you.

Comment: you should also copy the file to your home directory if you want to use your `.vimrc` :)

Comment: I create a new ~/.vimrc file again.Now everything is OK:)